# Mathjax 2.5 alpha

Tags: support, mathjax

We have deployed the latest Mathjax 2.5 alpha on Math.SE.  As with any beta release please post an answer to this question if you find any issues. We will be monitoring this thread closely along with the authors of Mathjax to ensure this release goes smoothly.

This particular release has a new feature that we need your help testing. Here's a direct quote from Davide Cervone & Peter Krautzberger from the MathJax team:

We are hoping to get feedback on one specific new feature: the **"Fast preview"** rendering mode.

**This is an opt-in test.**

You can activate the Fast Preview mode via the MathJax menu:

$$X^2 ---------------------------- X^2$$

```
right/cmd click an equation such as the one above => 
    click Math Settings => 
    click Math Renderer => 
    check "Fast Preview".  (Not "Fast HTML"; see below.)
```

This mode works as follows:

1. the new Fast HTML output creates a fast-but-rough preview
2. the HTML-CSS output runs and replaces the preview (or the SVG if you've switched manually)

[Note that the "Fast HTML" entry in the renderer list is the output format used by the fast preview temporarily before the output is replaced by the higher-quality output that MathJax normally produces.  If you select "Fast HTML" in the renderer list, that will keep the fast output permanently, rather than replacing it with the better version.  You can use that to see what the faster output look like.  We are working on improving the quality of this output, but those improvements won't come until after v2.5 is released.  We hope Fast HTML will be able to replace HTML-CSS in the future.]

There are a couple of variables we are hoping to tweak thanks to your feedback. Our main questions are:

a) Would you prefer the second run to show equations incrementally?

Right now, the second run will finish rendering all equations before replacing the Fast-HTML previews. This reduces jitter and speeds up the second run. It can be configured to show equations one-by-one or in chunks (e.g., 50, then 100 more, then 200 more).

b) how responsive is your browser during the second run?

Right now, the second run is optimized to keep your browser very responsive; this prolongs the second run slightly and can be tweaked in either direction.

These are questions of balancing the two runs and we hope your feedback here will allow us to strike the right balance.

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Thanks to the Stack Exchange team for helping us at MathJax and thanks to the community for any feedback!

Comment: Just to confirm: one does not have to choose "Fast HTML" renderer in order for "Fast preview" to be active, is this correct?

Comment: @Raff, Correct.  "Fast Preview" will use the fast output temporarily as the page is loaded, and replace the results with the usual MathJax output after it has been processed (behind the scenes) more slowly.  This gives you fast but less polished math until the better version is available.  If you select "Fast HTML", then the fast math is left in place permanently (you are selecting that as your renderer rather than the higher quality HTML-CSS or SVG output).

Comment: @Raff no. The preview works with the other outputs (HTML-CSS  and SVG). If you select the "Fast HTML" output, you would only get the first quick&dirty run. That new output is not yet finished which is why it is currently designed as a preview (e.g., it doesn't use webfonts); we plan to bring it up to quality in the release after. EDIT: Davide beat me to it ;-)

Comment: Great! I reckoned a search in Ron Gordon's posting history was a good strategy to find a MathJax heavy answer, and [here it is](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562694/integral-int-11-frac1x-sqrt-frac1x1-x-ln-left-frac2-x22-x1/565626#565626) if you want to try out the new rendering feature. There might be heavier posts out there and whoever finds one can feel free to add a link as a comment here.

Comment: @DanielR I'll try to reproduce this. Which Chrome version?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Version 33.0.1750.146

Comment: [This page also has a lot of mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), if someone is interested.

Comment: @DanielR hm. I failed to reproduce this (see https://saucelabs.com/tests/c7d8bd692591465aa27f10888033bbfe). It sounds like the pre-processor runs into trouble. Do you get any errors in the developer console? Does a page refresh, navigating away, or a change of output renderer fix it?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I somehow managed to mix "Fast HTML" and "Fast preview" in the instructions above and got the impression that the Fast HTML temporary rendering would be enabled by default. I does indeed work as intended. Sorry about the confusion and the time spilt. I will delete my comments.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the feedback -- that's relief :D no need to delete from my end -- perhaps we should clarify the text of the OP?

Comment: It seems that the renderer setting is set for meta site and the main site separately. So, changing the renderer option using the formula in the post will not change it on the main site, which is where the actual testing needs to be done.

Comment: Perhaps the ol' "Limits catalog" by our friend The @Raff is a suitable MathJax monster. (And indeed it is not for those with a timid CPU and RAM restrictions.) [It's your computer's funeral](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16717/catalog-of-limits).

Comment: Wow. I tested the limits catalog, and the fast preview was indeed fast. The browser remained responsive, and only had about one second where it was hanging, then the HTML-CSS output appeared and it was fairly smooth. (Intel Q9550, 4gb RAM, Linux 3.17.4 64bit, Firefox 34.0.5)

Comment: Good idea, @AsafKaragila. I also tried editing one of the post, and it's a much better experience with 2.5a. I would take the current behavior (second run done all at once) over incremental rendering. There is an (inevitable, I suppose) vertical displacement of text with the second run, and I'd rather not have it more than once. The browser had no issues during the second run. The first run gave it a little pause on the "Catalog of Limits", but this is indeed an extreme case.

Comment: @Raff: Before we settle on full second-run, or chunky monkey second-run we should at least give some chance for testing on things which are not desktop computers with four processing cores and 4gb of RAM (with a relatively light Linux installation too). For example, on my 32bit Atom tablet I might not be able to sustain Jax-heavy pages with a single second-run. And I'm not the only one who uses weaker processors often (see all those people using tablets and smartphones).

Comment: @DavideCervone In [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/815910/147263), fast preview renders far too right on the page, overlapping sidebar. Seen in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @Raff Thanks! That's a bug in the new output; I just filed it at https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/968

Comment: @AsafKaragila the "single second-run" is computationally less heavy since it triggers fewer page reflows. We have also improved the performance of the regular HTML-CSS output btw.

Comment: @WarmFuzzies, The problem is due to the `\tag` in the formula.  There are a number of features not yet implemented in the fast output, and equation labels is one of them.  Another is horizontal stretchy characters (like over- and underbraces), and a third is variants like `\cal` and `\frak` (which reference the MathJax fonts, but don't cause them to be loaded).  That is one reason that the fast output is just a preview at the moment.  We will have a more full-featured version the the release following 2.5, however.

Comment: @Davide: When you say `\cal` and `\frak` do you mean those directly, or do you include `\mathcal{}` and `\mathfrak{}` as well?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I mean all the methods of producing those fonts.  Again, these are things that we will be fixing in the future, but the current preview is limited in this way.

Comment: Okay, I tried to load the limit catalog from my Atom 32bit tablet. And it was relatively painless. The fast render is good. I give it my okay, for whatever it's worth. (I probably should add that with the previous version, loading on the Atom machine the limit catalog, even halfway through its conception, caused me to kill Firefox once and reboot once.)

Comment: ^ similar experience on my year-old Chromebook, with modest CPU. Certainly a big improvement on the past experience, with no new downsides. The preview may not be very pleasant to look at, but I can read it and scroll it.

Comment: In [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1052286/) it's apparent that the fast preview renders all inline operator limits as if in the display mode, resulting in large vertical displacement.

Comment: @Behaviour, thanks for the pointer.  Yes, moveable limits are not implemented yet in the fast preview.  I'll open an issue tracker for that and see if we can get it included in the 2.5 release.

Comment: The problem with this preview feature is that when you read the fast-rendered page at some spot, and MathJax finally finishes the rendering, replacing all the equations suddenly moves the viewport of the page, so that you have to scroll and search where you've been reading. This is quite an annoyance. Can there be a way to prevent such jumps? (I'm using Chromium)

Comment: @Ruslan, your point is well taken.  I'm not sure I know a good solution to the problem.  I've spent sometime experimenting, and nothing has worked out very well.  I'll keep thinking about it and see if I can get something that does what you request., but it may not be perfect.

Comment: 1) Can you prioritize formulae currently shown? The rest can be rendered in the background or even lazily. (Lazy would also solve the skipping problem.) 2) I notice (with the limits list) that you torture one CPU pretty hard while the others idle. Make use of multi-cores which most modern systems have; rendering formulae should almost always be embarrassingly parallelisable. (Might have to filter out `newcommand` and such, but still.)

Comment: @DavideCervone I don't know if this is new with 2.5, but I noticed that round parentheses as delimiters now [require quadruple backslash](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/18714/) instead of double. Not clear if this is intentional or a bug.

Comment: @Behaviour, this appears to be an error in the configuration used at SE.  Note that it specifies inline delimiters as `inlineMath: [ ["$", "$"], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"]` which means the delimiters are `\\(` and `\\)` rather than `\(` and `\)`.  So in Markdown, you need to use `\\\\(` and `\\\\)` to get the right number of backslashes.  In contrast, the display delimiters are `displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["\\[", "\\]"] ]`, which translates to a single backslash each, as expected.  So someone has over escaped the inline delimiters.

Comment: Hopefully, @Geoff Dalgas can fix the over-escaping. ^

Comment: Overlapping LaTeX in the "duplicate" section : http://gyazo.com/a70eddb1678a44ec75277ff8f1475678. I am unsure if this is due to the new LaTeX or not.

Comment: @Raphael JavaScript is single-threaded. The only way around this would be webworkers but that's not really feasible for MathJax right now (see this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449687/multi-core-programming-using-javascript) for some aspects).

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this is new in 2.5, but: I'm seeing a lack of spacing before the aligned symbol in the `aligned` environment. Tested in Firefox 33 and 35 and Safari 8 on OS X 10.10.

Here is a sample:
$$\begin{aligned}
u_t-u_{xx} &= p(x,t) \\
u(x,0) &= 0
\end{aligned}$$

Compare with the same code, wrapped in the similar `align` environment:
$$\begin{align}
u_t-u_{xx} &= p(x,t) \\
u(x,0) &= 0
\end{align}$$

Screenshot:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed report.  I'll look into it.  I think it is due to a change in 2.4, but should be fixed.

Comment: I've added an [issue tracker](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/982) for the problem

Comment: @DavideCervone That is not an issue. `aligned` shouldn't be used in replace of `align` which offers the spacing. One generally uses `aligned` inside of `align`. Here is the information on `aligned`. That is, the environment is working how it is intended. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111891/aligned-environment-of-amsmath-vs-array-environment

Comment: @dustin How do you propose to type up the following with `align`? $$\left\{\begin{aligned}
u_t-u_{xx} &= p(x,t) \\
u(x,0) &= 0
\end{aligned}\right.$$

Comment: Like so $$\begin{cases} u_t - u_{xx} &= p(x,t)\\ u(x,0) &= 0\end{cases}$$ The cases environment is made for that.

Comment: @dustin That looks rather awful.

Comment: You can redefine the environment as you need but there is an environment to achieve that look.

Comment: Or you can use array with rcl. There are literally numerous options. If you want to get into specifics, ask on TeX.SX.

Comment: [case alignment options](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124751/alignment-in-cases) here you go asked and answered with how to align to the right. Of course, you will need to adapt it to your specific need but the info is there.

Comment: @dustin Or we could have the `aligned` environment fixed, since [it's one of the environments that MathJax supports officially](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#environments), and has been used by plenty of other users on this site. The uses of `align` and `aligned` are different, so I rather resent your downvote.

Comment: That isn't fixing the environment. It is working properly. You received the down vote because there is nothing wrong with the environment it is working as intended.

Comment: @dustin No it's not. Compare with the output of the same code in LaTeX.

Comment: All I can say is check out the LaTeX documentation on the `amsmath` package. You will find the definition of `aligned` and you will see it isn't broken. It is doing what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @dustin [Here is how the spacing appears in the `texdoc amsmath` .pdf file.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GYIzX.png) Care to try again?

Comment: Read link post to David to get an understanding of the construct of the placement near a separated. All you need to do is read the first answers line. Also, you will notice `aligned` is used inside another environment like I said it generally is. You are using it as a standalone.

Comment: @dustin That does not justify the fact that the rendered output looks different (and uglier) in MathJax.

Comment: Well you are using it incorrectly and getting the correct results.

Comment: @dustin And I disagree strongly. That's that.

Comment: @dustin, I believe that epimorphic is correct, and that the link you cited actually shows that.  It says "a trick adjusts things so that `x&=y` gives the right spacing around the equals sign", which is *not* currently happening in MathJax.  Epimorphic's example shows that, and I have confirmed it in the code.  He is correct that LaTeX does include this space, and it *is* a bug in MathJax.  I have a fix for it and will be applying it to the next version of MathJax.

Comment: @DavideCervone I am aware of `{}` I use it all the time with `alignat`. It doesn't include the space because it has r aligned not l. Using the `aligned` inside another environment, works better.

Comment: @DavideCervone [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8788/which-one-should-i-use-beginalign-or-beginaligned) is a post addressing that `aligned` should be used inside of another environment. The issue they are having is due to using it alone.

Comment: @dustin Following the suggestion of the top answer at your link, here's the output of `\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}...` and `$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}...`: \begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
u_t-u_{xx} &= p(x,t) \\
u(x,0) &= 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation} $$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
u_t-u_{xx} &= p(x,t) \\
u(x,0) &= 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$ I still see the spacing issue. As such, your statement "the issue they are having is due to using it alone" is completely and utterly wrong.

Comment: @Dustin, the issue has nothing to do with whether it is used alone on in another environment.  MathJax handles it the same in both cases, and the lack of space before the equal sign has nothing to do with whether it is used in another environment or not.  Trust me, I wrote the code.  Epimophic is correct that the spacing in MathJax is wrong and needs to be fixed.  You are correct that `aligned` does belong inside another environment, but MathJax is not that strict about it.  Believe me, that has nothing to do with the spacing issue.

Answer (score 4):

Double vertical bars `\| \|`, typically used as the norm notation, render slanted by the Fast HTML renderer. For example, $\|R(f)-R(g)\|\le \|f-g\|$ becomes

> [image: bars]

I understand the fonts are rough but this looks like a wrong character altogether.

Single vertical bars are not affected.

Comment: The Fast HTML output doesn't currently use web fonts, so it relies on the fonts on your system.  It requests Times, but unfortunately,  this font doesn't include many math symbols, and the double vertical bar is one.  So it takes that from other font on your system.  Unfortunately, fonts don't seem to agree on whether this character should be vertical or slanted.  Currently, MathJax used U+2225 (parallel to), and perhaps that should be U+2016 instead, but even that is not uniformly treated as vertical lines.  Once we start to use web fonts for Fast HTML, this will be taken care of.

Answer (score 4):

Numbered equations have numbers on the left in the Fast HTML output:

> [image: fast]

unlike the HTML-CSS output:

> [image: final]

Also, the number is very close to the equation itself, despite there being plenty of room on the line.  [Seen here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1086387/147263).

Comment: The Fast HTML output doesn't yet implement the `<mlabeledtr>` MathML element (for a labeled table row) that is used for equation numbers.  I have modified the Fast HTML output to remove the label rather than place it incorrectly (it was also causing the table columns to misalign).  Again, the Fast HTML is not feature-complete at this point, and we will be expanding and improving it in the future.  That's why we are using it only as a preview for now.